# Run GraphicsMagick / ImageMagick on Ubuntu, targeted for Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, imagemagick, conversion

I'm trying to perform a `.emf` to `.png` conversion on a Ubuntu 16.04 server.

Unfortunately `.emf` is a proprietary Windows format and so will not work natively.

I'm therefore trying to build GraphicsMagick for Windows and hopefully execute it with `wine`.

I've tried building from source with the following

`./configure '--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32' '--disable-shared'` as per the [instructions here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-unix.html#cross-compilation-on-unix-linux-host)

But upon make it's failing with

```
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -D_LIB -D_MT -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -MT coders/magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-clipboard.lo -MD -MP -MF coders/.deps/magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-clipboard.Tpo -c coders/clipboard.c -o coders/magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-clipboard.o
coders/clipboard.c:44:24: fatal error: wingdi.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:8199: recipe for target 'coders/magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-clipboard.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [coders/magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-clipboard.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/GraphicsMagick-1.3.25'
Makefile:4437: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Download the precompiled version: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

Comment: Are you able to convert .emf to .png on wine? I'm able to execute ImageMagick portable x64 and convert jpg to png but emf gives me several errors like: fixme:gdiplus:GdipPlayMetafileRecord Not implemented for record type 401f

Comment: I never could, I used an emf2png.exe I found under wine but the images came out greyscale!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [Ipor Sircer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/182562/ipor-sircer), you'd probably be better off just downloading the [Windows binaries](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) provided by ImageMagick.

If you really want to build it from source, you need to install the MinGW-w64 cross-compiler:

```
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
```

and restart the build process (`./configure` etc.).